# Query performance - select only if exists

Tags: sql, sql-server, query-performance

I'm trying to make my query more efficient. This is a row-by-row check and many times the query won't make it to the update point due to no matching records. I *(EDIT)* <s>know</s> thought the best way to do this is by checking if there is a match first, then executing the query. Take this following real case example, where I try to minimize the performance costs:

```
/* LOOPING FROM MIN(ID) TILL MAX(ID) */
IF EXISTS(SELECT *
            FROM InvoicesHC IHC
                INNER JOIN ContractSpecifications CS ON IHC.ContractSpecificationID = CS.ContractSpecificationID
                INNER JOIN InstalledProductGroups IPG ON IPG.InstalledProductGroupID = CS.InstalledProductGroupID
                INNER JOIN ProductGroups PG ON PG.ProductGroupID = IPG.ProductGroupID
                INNER JOIN ContractFinYears CFY ON IHC.ContractFinYearID = CFY.ContractFinYearID
            WHERE PG.ProductGroupID = 2 AND IHC.ContractNr = @CCODE AND CFY.ContractFinYear = @CYEAR)
    BEGIN
            UPDATE InvoicesHC SET InvoicePrice = @IGAS, PONumber = @POCO
            FROM InvoicesHC IHC
                INNER JOIN ContractSpecifications CS ON IHC.ContractSpecificationID = CS.ContractSpecificationID
                INNER JOIN InstalledProductGroups IPG ON IPG.InstalledProductGroupID = CS.InstalledProductGroupID
                INNER JOIN ProductGroups PG ON PG.ProductGroupID = IPG.ProductGroupID
                INNER JOIN ContractFinYears CFY ON IHC.ContractFinYearID = CFY.ContractFinYearID
            WHERE PG.ProductGroupID = 2 AND IHC.ContractNr = @CCODE AND CFY.ContractFinYear = @CYEAR
    END
```

So I'm first checking if it exists, then I actually execute it. This should make the query run faster, but what I dislike is the fact that I actually copy-paste the same query over again - and within a T-SQL with 6 times a check like this, it becomes very big - more bigger than it actually should look like in my opinion. Another concern of me is the performance:  I already join the tables together (now just 4 inner joins, but what if there would be a lot more) to find if the record matches, then join them together over again to do the update query. In a small dataset what I'm using, it's not a big deal. But what if this row-by-row check should be executed millions of times?

I believe there should be a more efficient way to create this statement? Does somebody have any ideas?

Thanks.

Comment: Running the query twice is really faster?  Do you have a reference for this?  (I can see some benefits in terms of locking but I wouldn't think this would be a big optimization.)

Comment: "I know the best way to do this is by checking if there is a match first, then executing the query." - how do you know that? What about efficiency, then SQL is usually best for set-based operations - update all records with single statement for example.

Comment: Are you afraid of updating non-existent rows?

Comment: I don't have any reference for that, so I'm starting to doubt now. My main problem is that I have to loop throuh ProductGroupID 2 till ProductGroupID 8, which would mean that I'm updating 7 times this size of joined-query per iteration, even if nothing is found in any of the 7 cases.

Comment: Your assumptions are incorrect. An `UPDATE` statement with a `WHERE` clause will update only the rows that match the criteria. It will do so in a single operation and cost nothing more than the search if no rows are found. On the other hand, a loop is the worst possible solution performance-wise - you pay the full price of a select for each individual row, keep locks for a lot longer than necessary and can have knock-on effects as the creeping locks block other operations

Comment: To improve performance, write a single `UPDATE` statement with the proper `WHERE` clause and ensure the table has covering indexes to speed up the search

Comment: Oh stupid of me. Made a big mistake there. Thanks!

Comment: Why do you loop instead of `WHERE PG.ProductGroupID >= 2 AND PG.ProductGroupID <= 8 AND ...`?

Comment: I need to map 1 column in the old record set to 1 specific productgroupid in the new schema, to enter the query of the example above a condition must be met. same (different conditions) for the others.

Comment: Have you thought about utilizing indexes and statistics to increase your query speeds?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This one should be fine:

```
        UPDATE InvoicesHC SET InvoicePrice = @IGAS, PONumber = @POCO
        FROM InvoicesHC IHC
            INNER JOIN ContractSpecifications CS ON IHC.ContractSpecificationID = CS.ContractSpecificationID
            INNER JOIN InstalledProductGroups IPG ON IPG.InstalledProductGroupID = CS.InstalledProductGroupID
            INNER JOIN ProductGroups PG ON PG.ProductGroupID = IPG.ProductGroupID
            INNER JOIN ContractFinYears CFY ON IHC.ContractFinYearID = CFY.ContractFinYearID
        WHERE PG.ProductGroupID = 2 AND IHC.ContractNr = @CCODE AND CFY.ContractFinYear = @CYEAR
```

Answer (score 0):

> but what I dislike is the fact that I actually copy-paste the same
>   query over again - and within a T-SQL with 6 times a check like this,
>   it becomes very big

I think you should use Merge.Using merge reduce those repeat query again and again.And performance wise at least it would be better than earlier code.

This is just demo.

```
MERGE InvoicesHC AS TRG
USING (
SELECT InvoicesHC
            FROM InvoicesHC IHC
                INNER JOIN ContractSpecifications CS ON IHC.ContractSpecificationID = CS.ContractSpecificationID
                INNER JOIN InstalledProductGroups IPG ON IPG.InstalledProductGroupID = CS.InstalledProductGroupID
                INNER JOIN ProductGroups PG ON PG.ProductGroupID = IPG.ProductGroupID
                INNER JOIN ContractFinYears CFY ON IHC.ContractFinYearID = CFY.ContractFinYearID
            WHERE PG.ProductGroupID = 2 AND IHC.ContractNr = @CCODE AND CFY.ContractFinYear = @CYEAR
)as SRC
on trg.ContractNr=src.ContractNr
When matched then
    update 
        SET InvoicePrice = @IGAS, PONumber = @POCO;
```

Comment: This is no different than an `UPDATE` statement with a `WHERE`, just more complex. At best the optimizer will create the same execution plan as the `UPDATE` statement